# WordPress - Shortcode does not run, can't figure it out

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I have create my own slideshow plugin.
When I use do_shortcode(); everything works fine.

But if I just run the_content();
The shortcode is not executing.

```
$sprinter_slideshow = new sprinter_slideshow();
class sprinter_slideshow{

private $data_created = FALSE;
function sprinter_slideshow(){
    add_shortcode('sprinter_slideshow', array(&$this, 'sprinter_slideshow_shortcode'));

    add_action('init', array(&$this, 'initialize_sprinter'));
    //add_action('the_posts', array(&$this, 'check_for_shortcode'));
}
```

as you can see, I create an instance of the class and directly add the shortcode to the register.

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can we see the actual sprinter_slideshow::sprinter_slideshow_shortcode method? Also, what version of php is that? I believe that the old constructor style is still accepted, but it should be a public method.

Comment: This php 4. Php 5.3 have just been dropped from any futher support.

Comment: The sprinter_slideshow_shortcode, is pretty much code, and there should not be any problem with that one, because:
THIS WORK: do_shortcode('[sprinter_slideshow target="attribute"]');
THIS DO NOT WORK: do_shortcode(get_the_content());

So the shortcode function works, I get a slideshow, but the shortcode request does not work.

I can see if i echo get_the_content(); that there is a &nbsp; between, slideshow&nbsp;target="
Can that be a problem?

What do you mean Pieter Goosen?